# Logging consistent request thread id with log4j when using CFX, Spring and DBCP

Tags: spring, log4j, tomcat7, spring-data, apache-commons-dbcp

Using the pretty standard stack of CFX and Spring for JAX-RS rest endpoints. I am also using DBCP for database connection pooling. Everything runs inside a tomcat container as a standard web-app. The issue I am trying to solve is to log a consistent thread-id on every log line. That way I can track a request end to end.

But the problem seems to be that Spring/DBCP is switching the thread to a different one, so the log line has thread ids all jumbled up. I can't track a single request end-to-end as a result.

Below is an example

```
2014-07-22 18:55:47,224 INFO ajp-bio-8034-exec-8 <log_line_omitted>
2014-07-22 18:55:47,226 INFO pool-10-thread-77   <log_line_omitted>
2014-07-22 18:55:47,299 INFO ajp-bio-8034-exec-8    <log_line_omitted>
```

As you can see, the thread id has changed from *ajp-bio-8034-exec-8* to *pool-10-thread-100* and back again.

Most likely the thread-id is switching because of the database connection pooling by DBCP.

What can I do go get a consistent view of the request end-to-end?

The log4j properties file uses the following layout

```
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on thread ids to track a request. Create a unique id for each request and add that to the MDC and log that with every line. Works regardless of the threads involved.